# No old orders, invoices, shipments, etc after Magento upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, invoice, sales

I've updated my old **1.4.0** Magento to the recent version **1.9.0.1**.

But after the update I noticed that there are no orders, invoices, shipments and actually no data related with old sales!

I bought a test product and I can see only 1 this order, no more.

What's wrong with that? (My custom modules/templates are currently off).

Comment: Did you encounter and errors on the upgrade?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: @brentwpeterson I started magento upgrade from scratch using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes#13201613) and I finished upgrading with success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is that between Magento version 1.4 and 1.5 there was a large restructuring of database tables with regards to sales.

The order tables in Magento 1.4 followed the following naming: `sales_order`
But in newer versions the name includes the word `flat` e.g. `sales_flat_order`.

I would suggest either looking into a database back, or if the tables are still there looking directly at the old tables. Check the data and structure and migrate across to the new tables.

Comment: I see that some data is still there: tables sales_flat_order_item, sales_flat_quote, sales_flat_quote_address, sales_flat_quote_item, sales_flat_quote_item_option, sales_flat_quote_payment, sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate. Everywhere is over 30-70K records. How to migrate that?

Comment: @SergiyMatrunchyk ah so the data has been migrated across to the new tables....I guess you might just have to find the piece of data missing. How did you to the upgrade?

Comment: First time it was by issuing the command: `./pear install magento-core/Mage_All_Latest`. And some part of upgrade it was made via Magento Connect Manager. Btw, there is no `sales_order` table and `sales_flat_order` contains only my 1 test order. So it seems that `sales_order` wasn't migrated to `sales_flat_order`. Right?

Comment: @SergiyMatrunchyk that is what I would suggest has happened. All the moving and droping of tables is done in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.3.99-1.4.0.0.php`

Comment: I understand, but how to migrate these tables manually (Even after the restoring the old one `sales_order` back)?

Comment: @SergiyMatrunchyk You should never have to manually migrate the tables, if this has happened then your upgrade did not execute correctly

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would do is review the Upgrade road map here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-upgrade-roadmap

After that you should test your upgrade using this method http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

The basic steps are as follows:

Back up your current database
Download version 1.9 and run this again your backed up database
Note any errors.

If your upgrade completes then you will be able to login to your admin and review your orders, customer, products and categories

Once you can do this you can start adding in modules (You will most likely have to upgrade some of your modules)

You will then need to resolve your theme problems.

You should be able to get through your upgrade and have to incrementally upgrade. I have personally upgraded many sites as far back as 1.2 -> current version. The exception to this upgrade is going to 1.13. You will need to incrementally upgrade for EE going to current versions. You should not have to do this for CE

Comment: The second link underwent Magentovaporation and is no longer in the official Magento website knowledge base. Brent has recorded it for posterity here => http://www.brentpeterson.net/2014/11/upgrade-using-fresh-install-and.html