# Orders disappeared

Tags: magento-1.7, database, upgrade, installation

I have upgraded my magento 1.3.2.4 to 1.7 but when I go to Sales --> Orders, it shows blank, and my lifetime sales and so forth is displayed as 0.

Now iv'e checked the sales_flat_order table, and it is empty. However, The table Sales_Order isn't and has the whole 31827 orders in there. I assume this is the old table used in 1.3.2.4.

So, I am wondering is it possible to take across order history or not ? and if so how can I ensure that it is kept in upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Magento 1.4, the database structure has undergone substantial changes.

However, it's still possible to transfer all order data without losing anything. Here is the thread, where you can find an answer to your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes

Comment: I  have gone through the upgrade and I am on 1.7 now. But orders in ver.1.3.2.4 were stored in the sales_order table. But 1.7 is in sales_flat_order. So, is there a way to transfer the orders to the new tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You should insert your old orders from sales_order table to sales_flat_order table. Manually add values for required fields if they are missing.

Comment: I have over 30,000 records so before going ahead with this, is there no other way and/or definite answer that it is not through a mistake or bad upgrade ?

Comment: Try to check comments to the applied answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33201/no-old-orders-invoices-shipments-etc-after-magento-upgrade. Are you sure that your setup script app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.3.99-1.4.0.0.php is installed well?

Comment: Have read through the post you've linked :) could you elaborate on installed well ?

Comment: I have checked that script you've mentioned but sadly looks like it is not fully running: it has lines to Remove previous tables, but they still exist, so I guessing it is not running properly. What can I do different if I go back and rerun upgrade for the nth time